# Changing sparsity structure for a single operation

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix `A` in `coo` format (which is created from `scipy.sparse.bmat`) :

```
A
<80000x80000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 278480 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I would like to

1. Change all values in a particular row of this matrix
2. Solve `spsolve(A, g)` for some `g` on the changed matrix

Now, I can't change rows in `coo` format. The following works:

```
AA = A.tocsr()
AA[10, :] = 1  # or whatever other array I want to put here
spsolve(AA, g)
```

but I will get a

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

Now, as far as I understand, `lil_matrix` is inefficient in solving linear algebra - so even if I had changed the sparsity structure to `lil`, I would/should have changed back to `csr` or `csc` afterwards.

In general, is that worth it? I don't want to speed test every single operation I am making here: Are there rule of thumbs of how costly "changing sparsity" versus "row slicing" versus "arithmetic operations" are? How do programmers typically deal with these kind of problems?

Comment: You can always do your own timings.  In my experience the 'efficiencywarning' is mainly there to keep you from doing this in a loop.  For one time change like this ignore it.  Conversion to `lil` is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the warning, a one time change to `csr` is better than the round trip through `lil`:

```
In [137]: %%timeit M = sparse.random(10,10,.2,format='csr')
     ...: M[-1,:] = np.arange(10)
     ...: 
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
204 µs ± 5.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [139]: %%timeit M = sparse.random(10,10,.2,format='csr')
     ...: M1=M.tolil(); M1[-1,:] = np.arange(10); M = M1.tocsr()
444 µs ± 9.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [141]: %%timeit M = sparse.random(10,10,.2,format='lil')
     ...: M[-1,:] = np.arange(10)
162 µs ± 84.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```